# How to manage many number of parameters for a same url with jersey-servlet

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, query-string

I am developing a REST API which has about 20 services. All are HTTP GET requests with same URL with different parameters for different services. All together there are about 100 parameters for the entire  API. I am using Jersey library for the API.Is there any better way to manage these huge number of parameters?

```
    @GET
    @Path("/processMessage")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response processMessage(
          @QueryParam("a") String a,
          @QueryParam("b") String b,
          @QueryParam("c") String c,
          @QueryParam("d") String d,
          @QueryParam("e") String e,
          @QueryParam("f") String f,
          @QueryParam("g") String g,
          @QueryParam("h") String h,
          @QueryParam("h") String z,
  )
}
```

`

Comment: what is the need for so many query parameters? did you try converting the long list to a json and then passing it to the rest API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all parameters using `UriInfo`:

```
public Response processMessage(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
     MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
```

Or [as a field](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/uri-info.html):

```
@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;
```

> An instance of UriInfo can be injected as field or method parameter using the @Context annotation. UriInfo provides access to application and request URI information